I'd like to hide certain stack exchange communities
There are some stack exchange sites that appear in the "Hot Network Questions" that I never want to see or participate in, and don't even want to be reminded of.  It's hard to ignore them because they are frequently displayed on that list.  I enjoy the Hot Network Questions list, but I don't want to see the question titles from those communities.
Can you please provide a way for me to say "don't show this community" so that it doesn't appear in my list?
This would just be a personal user preference setting.

This question is similar to: Filter "Hot Network Questions" by excluding sites. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Note that, using a site search, I found Use a taglike system for SE-sites in the Hot Network Questions which was closed as a duplicate of the proposed duplicate.
